# Is there a web application for phonetic English word searches?

Tags: localization

Is there a web application for doing phonetic English word searches? For example, if I search for words that contain the syllable "feet", I'd want my results to include:

- Feet
- Feat
- Fetal
- Defeat

I can't think of any more, but that's why I want this app. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Phonetic Word Search](http://www.benbriedis.com/phonetic/search.php) appears to do something like this, but you'll need to use their syntax to describe phonemes.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but the results are a bit wonky. I gave it ".* F IY T *.", meaning "starts with anything, then has F as in Fee, then E as in Eat, then T as in Tea, then ends with anything." My results included "beefeater", which is good, but also "audiophile" and "ionosphere," which are definitely wrong.

Comment: @NathanLong For the record: No the result is okay, your search term is wrong. Exchange the last two characters (`*.`) by `.*` and your result will look much better. Currently you set `T` as optional and repeatable by using the `*` right behind.